# Saving rooms in booking app

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, logic

I have some website for hotel reservation.
People who are aligible, can choose a hotel, dates and capacity and pay for the order.

When the client make the decision and clicks the order button a few steps heppens:

1. Application check again for price and gathering order information
2. Saving rooms for the client to prevent overbooking
3. A timer set to 5 min for client order window (if time is gone the rooms are released)

> If the client goes out the orger page a null_timer is trigered and
> saved rooms are released
>
> If the client starts order (in order page) he can't procced other
> orders

- `$_SESSION['order_iddle']` and **timer** changes triggered from
  client-side via ajax

**JS trigger**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 

      timer_null();   
      return ""; 

}
```

**PHP check**

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['order_iddle'])) || (!$_SESSION['order_iddle']) )  {

     header('location: https://home-page/');
     
}
```

- `$_SESSION['order_iddle']` updates with timer in php.
- `timer_null()` sends ajax request to php to update/check timer

### Question 1:

This logic relies on `onbeforeunload()` function, but if the function not working in some browser we have trouble. If there a better way to trigger `timer_null()` when user go away from order page? Maybe in PHP?

### Question 2:

When `onbeforeunload()` triggers and user clicks "Stay on the page", `timer_null()` triggered anyway.
Is there something to do with that?

#### *Thanks*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option would be to give the order an expiry value in your back end. This way you avoid triggering, problems when users don't use JS, problems when they stay on the page etc.

When they make an order set a value to the current time plus a number of minutes:

```
$order['expiry'] = time() + (5 * 60); // sets an expiry time for 5 minutes (5x60 seconds)
```

Then on a future page which checks whether the order is valid:

```
if (time() > $order['expiry']) {
     throw new Exception('This order is not valid');
}
```

Catch that exception and return it to the user however you'd like.

#### Suggestions for wider use

You might have other things in your use case which require, for example, stock to be held for those five minutes. However if you incorporate this expiry into your data store as well then it can be used to check expiries on any future orders.

If you wanted to not have to be checking thousands of potentially expired records each time a new order is made you could create a sort of "clean-up" script to run automatically. If you've not used `crontab` before I suggest your read up on it, but a script set to run at midnight every day with crontab:

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/my-clean-up-script.php
```

Then in the script itself (pseudo-code):

```
$expired_orders = database_query ( GET orders FROM table WHERE expired_time < current_time)
for each $expired_orders
    database_query ( DELETE order)
```

Which should work for any queryable data store.

Comment: thanks, the first part already implemented ($_SESSION['order_iddle'] == $order['expiry']). about the cron jobs, it's the last choice for me, because we can not wait till night when php will release the rooms and set cron every 5 min... well its a big db... Any chance for client-side trigger too?

Comment: As mentioned in your question and the answer though, it's not possible to guarantee that the client side JS will be executed correctly. You don't need it to be client side if you simply check whether the time is greater. The cron job was a later suggestion but the simple time check would work for what you've described as your use case. Unless your database is going to be >100,000 records per day I doubt you'd get an issue searching it once a night.

Comment: searching it once a night not a performance issue, just may be a few rooms available for hotel in some date, so other people will not be able to order untill the taken rooms will be released. And yes, it's only 10% of hope is left for me about client-side trigger)

Comment: Using the code above, where an expiry time is set at the point of order and then subsequently checked when further orders are requested, will make the rooms available 5 minutes after the order expires. The cron section is a later suggestion to clean your database; the original code meets the use case you're specifying.

Comment: it's works now, let's wait a week and find some bugs)